# How can the VHS steganography question be made on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

This question is about this question: [How can extra (digital) data be hidden on VCR/VHS tapes?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18129/278)

I think this is a good question. I like it, it's interesting, and its answers provide insight into the real-world characteristics of VHS tapes.

It's been closed, and I think that's a shame. What can we do to make this question on-topic?

Comment: Possibly the question is too open ended.  It neither qualifies as a question about actual history, nor is the poster interested in actually pursuing a modern solution to this problem. I think questions about hypothetical historical situations will always be off topic here.

Comment: Guilty as charged. The question was a nice and well formed puzzle, so I gave in - despite the fact that it is in no way computer related - eventually except the fact that he wants to use one. All details and solutions are purely analogue and based on analogue material and tools. So as pipe says, World building is a better place - despite the hardware/compute/technical elements.

Comment: On-topic to retrocomputing specifically?

Comment: @snips-n-snails That was my _intention_, yes.

Answer (score 9):

Migrate it to [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) where they are used to answer open-ended hypothetical but science-based questions:

- [Where could you obtain neon/argon in 1931 Las Vegas?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/177590/17450)
- [How would one develop a transistor in a medieval setting](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/112654/17450)
- [What would be the best way to get clean, drinkable water in a medieval city?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/39896/17450)